# Можно ли как-то улучшить intelisense в vs code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Пишу на C++, установленные расширения ниже. Intelisense ужасно работает, раньше сидел в visual studio и там вроде было лучше, а тут... не знаю конечно, может только у меня такая проблема, но например когда я делаю include какого-то хедера то ему не важно его местоположение, он принимает любой путь, и только на этапе компиляции мне компилятор говорит о ошибке. Точно не помню, но вроде он еще подсвечивал похожие слова на название класса. Да и в принципе, пишу код, ошибок не говорит, компилирую - компилятор посылает меня далеко и надолго.

[image: 1] [image: 2]

Может надо расширение поставить какое-то? Или еще что-то

Comment: Жаль, что на SO нельзя минусовать комментарии. Какая связь между ИИ и автодополнением? По теме вопроса, попробуйте расширение clangd

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Вместо минуса тыкаете на флажок, затем "больше не нужен". Про Clangd - поддерживаю.

Comment: У меня это вроде нормально работает (кроме `<compare>` и `<concepts>`, которые упорно считает неиспользуемыми). [Вот тут](https://clangd.llvm.org/config) почитайте. Надо создать конфиг-файл, и там указать `Diagnostics:` `UnusedIncludes: None`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я сделал это в конфиге в appdata, теперь другой вопрос возникает. Как ему подключить, например, glm? Я думал с скопированием compile_commands в корневую папку все исправится, но нет. Использую cmake

Comment: Он должен подхватить из compile_commands.json все библиотеки сам. Перезапустите vsc на всякий. Проверьте во вкладке output->clangd, что он его нашёл и берет оттуда флаги для вашего .cpp-шника.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat сейчас вроде все видит, спасибо